# Set a value of the independent picklist

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to make a picklist dependent on another one
Controller picklist:Subtype
Dependent picklist
I succeded to do this
I put it in a lightning component

```
<ui:inputSelect aura:id="conType" label="Type" class="slds-select" change="{!c.onControllerFieldChange}" value="{!v.TypeV}">
<ui:inputSelect aura:id="conSubtype" label="Sub Type" value="{!v.SubTypeV}" disabled="{!v.isDependentDisable}" class="slds-select"  />
```

I put this component  from another lightning component

DependentSubtype is the child component
TypeV child component attribute to initialize the value of controller picklist (Type)
SubTypeV child component attribute to initialize the value of dependent picklist (SubType)

For the Controller picklist (Type) the initialization works
But for the dependent picklis (Subtype) it doesn't
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your approach is right, **however**, its difficult to point out the problem from just that two lines of code. Here is a approach for dependent picklist,

```js
// controller.js
({
  doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.loadOption1(component, event);
  },
  
  changeSecondPicklist : function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.populateOption2(component, event);
  }
})

// helper.js
({
  loadOption1 : function(component, event) {
    var option = [];
    option.push('Type1.1');
    option.push('Type1.2');
    option.push('Type1.3');
    component.set('v.option1', option);
  },
  
  populateOption2 : function(component, event) {
    var value = event.getParam('value');
    var option = [];
    if (value == 'Type1.1') {
      option.push('SubType1.1');
      option.push('SubType1.2');
      option.push('SubType1.3');
    }
    else if (value == 'Type1.2') {
      option.push('SubType2.1');
      option.push('SubType2.2');
      option.push('SubType2.3');
    }
    else {
      option.push('SubType3.1');
      option.push('SubType3.2');
      option.push('SubType3.3');
    }
    component.set('v.option2', option);
  }
})
```

```html
<!-- lightning component -->
<aura:component>
  <aura:attribute name="option1" type="String[]" />
  <aura:attribute name="option2" type="String[]" />
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

  <lightning:select name="select1" label="Type" required="true" onchange="{!c.changeSecondPicklist}">
    <option value="">choose one...</option>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.option1}" var="item">
      <option value="{!item}">{!item}</option>
    </aura:iteration>
  </lightning:select>

  <lightning:select name="select2" label="SubType" required="true">
    <option value="">choose one...</option>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.option2}" var="item">
      <option value="{!item}">{!item}</option>
    </aura:iteration>
  </lightning:select>
</aura:component>
```

Here I have used *lightning* tag as Salesforce is going discontinue support for *ui* tags. The logic is **onchange** event of first picklist populates the options of dependent picklist.